# in new GCP instance "dnf update" hangs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, rocky-os

```
[root@instance-2 ant2ne]# dnf update
Google Compute Engine                                                           24 kB/s | 9.4 kB     00:00    
Google Cloud SDK                                                                26 MB/s | 149 MB     00:05
```

hangs

New instance. Just fired it up.

I was expecting it update. Or to fail. Not just hang. This hang wont ^C or ^V out of it. I have to power of the instance.

Rocky 9 x86_64 GCP instance.

Comment: What do "dnf.log" and "dnf.librepo.log" show? They are located in /var/log.